# When creating content with new term, show all term fields for input also

Tags: 7, taxonomy-terms

Taxonomy terms are clubs and there are many in vocabulry, with fields to enter address, long/lat etc.

User adds content Concert and can pick a club (terms) from Simple Hierarchical select. 
If club is not in vocabulary user can add new term. While doing this he should also be able to input fields for new term (address, long/lat) while creating content.

How can i achieve this ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use combination of two modules. First is [Entity Reference](https://www.drupal.org/project/entityreference), where you have to create your taxonomy term reference field. Then install module [Inline Entity Form](https://www.drupal.org/project/inline_entity_form) and use widget `Inline entity form - Multiple values` (in number of values of this field select: 1).

In node create form you will have then field, where you can select from existing terms (autocomplete) and also you will be able to create new term, if term does no exists - this will create inline form, which would have all fields specified in taxonomy vocabulary structure (see image below).
[image: taxonomy term inline form]

If you select existing term, or create new, it will looks like this:
[image: taxonomy term selected]

Comment: Thx Jure, this works nice. Only problem left is hierarchy. For example user wants to add club in Ljubljana, so he should choose parent term (Ljubljana), and add new child term after.